# OpenGL ES CustomView extends GLSurfaceView content

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have my main activity as follows.I set the content view to sfgameview's instance. I also have a renderer somewhat like(at bottom) but i am missing the sfgameview's content(99% chance) or something that's making my app crash.

```
package ---;

imports ---;    

public class Main extends Activity {

private SFGameView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new SFGameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    gameView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    gameView.onResume();
}

}
```

Renderer:

```
package ---;

imports ---;

public class SFGameRenderer implements Renderer {

variables---;

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000/60);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, -1f, 1f);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig arg1) {

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);

    variable.loadTexture(gl, BACKGROUND_LAYER_ONE,
            context);
    variable2.loadTexture(gl, BACKGROUND_LAYER_TWO,
            context);
}
```

}

SFGameView:

```
package com.proandroidgames;

imports---;

public class SFGameView extends GLSurfaceView {

public SFGameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //this is empty and i dont know what to put..

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big thing you're missing is gameView.setRenderer(new SFGameRenderer()). There's a lot of stuff missing here so any of these could be causing things to crash.

You can get a running sample from [Android OpenGL Training](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) or [Android Lesson One: Getting Started](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/). Disclaimer: I maintain the second linked site.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.